# What is different between hql update and object update in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am using hibernate-4.3.11.Final.
As you know there are two way to update in database.
First one is hql update is used in repository for example:

```
update Account e 
   set e.count= 12
 where e.id = 123
```

Second way is that This Object is loaded from database by id and set count by setter method of this Object for example(in the service):

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean changeTempCount(Integer id, Integer count) {
        Account model = iAccountRepository.loadById(id);
        model.setCount(count);
        super.save(model);
        return true;
    }
```

Both of them are worked successfully
I want to know that each of them is better than another or what is different
between those

Answer (score 0):

First of all, one thing you really need to understand is that the call to `super.save(model);` is unnecessary. Hibernate transparently writes the changes made to entities, without any need to explicitly save anything. Entities loaded from the database by Hibernate (using one of the get()/load() methods, or a query, or by navigating through associations) are *managed* which means that Hibernate tracks their changes and saves them for you.

Now, regarding your question;

- an HQL update won't deal with optimistic concurrency (i.e. `@Version`-annotated fields): the version won't be checked nor updated
- an HQL update won't update the entity in memory. So if you load an entity, and then execute an update query, the database will be affected, but the entity in memory will stay in the state where it was when initially loaded into the session.

Comment: Thanks your excellent answer I have HQL update and i want that this Object understand  my change in memory.How do i do?

Comment: You don't do an update. Or you `refresh()` the object after the update.

Comment: What is your idea because of concurrency i refresh after update instead of load Object and call setter of it. Is it ok?

Comment: I don't see any point of using an update query. Why don't you just update the entity, and let Hibernate do the update in database for you?

Comment: Because of concurrency

Comment: Why makes you think that your own update query will solve concurrency issues better than the same update query executed by Hibernate? What is the concurrency issue?

Comment: When i wrote this line of code 'session.refresh(Acount.class);' this exception is raised: '[ERROR] org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Class Unknown entity: java.lang.Class'

Comment: refresh() expects an Account instance to refresh. Not a class.